# building a tree lambda expression for generic list

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, system.reflection, anonymous-delegates

I have a method through an ObjectDataSource feeds a gridview and allows sorting by column using lambda expressions:

```
    public IList<UsersEntity> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<UsersEntity>(new[] {
            new UsersEntity{ UsrId =1, UsrName="Luis" }, 
            new UsersEntity{ UsrId = 2, UsrName = "Pablo"} });
    }

    public IList<UsersEntity> GetUsers(string OrderBy)
    {
        string[] ordParts = OrderBy.Split(' ');
        string ordBy = ordParts[0];
        string direction = "ASC";
        if (2 == ordParts.Length)
            direction = "DESC";

        //Get Unsorted List
        List<UsersEntity> Lista = (List<UsersEntity>)GetUsers();

        //Function to order 
        Func<UsersEntity, object> myFunct = null;
        myFunct = (usr) => {
            if ("UsrId" == ordBy) return usr.UsrId;
            else return usr.UsrName;
        };

        //sort list
        if ("ASC" == direction)
            return Lista.OrderBy(myFunct).ToList();
        else
            return Lista.OrderByDescending(myFunct).ToList();

    }
```

But I want something more functional, something that works for all types of lists and does not involve adding a lot of code. So I wrote this function that I can not complete:

```
public class OrdenarEntidades<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SortList(IEnumerable<T> Listado, string OrderByArg)
    {
        string[] arrOrderBy = OrderByArg.Split(' ');
        string orderBy = arrOrderBy[0];
        string direction = "ASC";
        if (2 == arrOrderBy.Length)
            direction = "DESC";

        foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (orderBy == pInfo.Name)
            {
                Type tipDev = pInfo.PropertyType;
                Func<T, tipDev> MyFunct = (Entity) => { pInfo.GetValue(Entity, null); };

                if ("ASC" == direction)
                    Listado.OrderBy(MyFunct);
                else
                    Listado.OrderBy(MyFunct);
            }
        }

        return Listado;
    }
}
```

I know this code does not compile, however expresses the idea of what I want to accomplish.

**[Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) gives an approximation to what I'm looking for ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet)), but do not know not how to adapt it to my code**

Beforehand, thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Comment: Thinking more about your question... What is the context you are going to use the function? Seems like a lot of trouble just to wrap linq functionality. Are OrderBy strings stored in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
public class OrdenarEntidades<T>
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> SortList(IEnumerable<T> Listado, params Func<T, object>[] orders)
    {
       if(orders.Length == 0)
           return Listado;
       IOrderedEnumerable<T> result = Listado.OrderBy(orders[0]);
       for(int i = 1; i < orders.Length; ++i)
           result = result.ThenBy(orders[i]);
       return result;
    }
}
```

This supports only ASCENDING order. To allow both directions wrap `Func<T, object>` in a class with the direction property based on which `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` is called.

The function can be called like this

```
var usersSorted = OrdenarEntidades<UserEntity>.SortList(users, user=>user.UsrId, user=>user.UsrName);
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Calling `OrderBy()` multiple times actually sorts just once, by the last sort used.

Comment: Surely, no sense at all. Replace subsequent `OrderBy`s with `ThenBy` to solve the problem.